# with all its pastures worn out

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> One of them, which was named Foxwood, was a large, neglected, old-fashioned farm, much overgrown by woodland, with all its pastures **worn out** and its hedges in a disgraceful condition.

From *Animal Farm*

What does **worn out** here mean? Does it mean:

1. The pastures became so poor that no plant would grow on it?
2. The pastures was neglected, full of weeds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means 1 - the pastures would no longer support a useful growth.
See *soil exhaustion* :

[soil exhaustion](https://sciencing.com/what-is-soil-exhaustion-13406891.html)